# PIGPIO stream pwm data over websockets with nodejs. GPIO

Tags: gpio, networking, node.js, pigpio

i use servoblaster, one of the first projects for PWM (pulse with modulation) on the raspberry pi. Now i got a new raspberry and i wanted to try the very promising **pigpio**. It looks really fast and properly done.

But i also want to be able to control everything over a simple html website which is driven by websockets, also a fast way to communicate between modern devices. websockets is supported on all new phones. When the connection is open, you start to send, in a bidirectional way, pure data! This makes it my favorite api to communicate with other devices/servers.

To communicate with servoblaster, nodejs needs to write the data somewhere.

servoblaster uses DMA (direct memory access). This allows you to not destroy your memorycard :), probably the fastest way to store information.
That stream location is `/dev/servoblaster`. In the Linux console you write

```
echo 0=50% > /dev/servoblaster
```

this sets the  GPIO-4 (which is 0 for the servoblaster) to 50% of the duty cycle. In nodejs probably the best and only way to continuosly write a stream is:

```
//WORKING
var fs=require('fs'),
stream=fs.createWriteStream('/dev/servoblaster');

stream.write('0=50%');
```

**the above code works perfect with servoblaster.but does not work with the pigpio**

i installed everything and tested various pigpio commands in the console.
Everything works in the console with pigpio, in nodejs NO.

```
//NOT WORKING
var fs=require('fs'),
stream=fs.createWriteStream('/dev/pigpio');

stream.write('p 4 255'); // turn on GPIO-4
// after a while i also tested
// stream.write('"p 4 255"');
```

the above code does not work.

**Said that, i hope you can help me figure out how to directly write the websocket stream (from nodejs) to the /dev/pigpio**

i changed also permissions to the **/dev/pigpio** but nothing.

Also if you know a better(i always only mean FASTER) way to directly write the needed data from websockets to the pigpio DMA location. i'm always rdy to learn new stuff.

**Notes:**

the working raspberry has a headless armhf wheezy version that uses only about 40mb-50mb ram with everything up and running (servoblaster & various nodejs servers).

i try to not use other languages than js(nodejs) & c to keep the memory impact low and also try to run everything from the ram. this makes it incredible fast.

i can animate(color tweens, light dimming using css or js) multiple light sources with pwm without lag. the animations are created clientside in javascript. it's simpler for me. And it works  great with websockets. Always consider the fact that i run this over HTTP.

i hope i can also properly test the **pigpio**!

Comment: I think you know that when looking for programming help, replacing "does not work" with a more specific description of the error will probably get you further, faster.   Especially when you have included a lot of extraneous clutter ;)

Comment: i know. nodejs outputs nothing. it appears to be as it writes the data correctly

Comment: using other methods give errors ... for example i tried to use writetofile and i got a seek error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands you can send via the pipe interface are shown at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html

---

For the pipe interface each command should be terminated in a new line character ("\n") and you may need to flush output to force the command through the system.  Mind you I'd expect you have to do exactly the same with servoblaster.

---

There are two PWM generating commands.

s *g* *us* # send servo pulses

p *g* *dc* # send PWM pulses

where *g* is the (Broadcom) gpio number, *us* is the servo pulse length in microseconds, and *dc* is the PWM dutycycle (out of 255).

Use the s command to control servos and ESCs.

Use the p command for LEDs and DC motors.

E.g.

s 4 2000 # send 2000µs pulses on gpio 4 (50Hz)

p 4 128 # send 50% dutycycle pulses on gpio 4 (default 800Hz)

Comment: omg i forgot the new line!! i'm an idiot.   yeah 3h for a stupid error like this thx joan ... btw very nice lib!!!!

Comment: You also this that is a good/fast way to write the info? or is there a faster way to send the pwm data to your pigpio?

Comment: I've never actually done any tests on relative performance between the pipe and socket interfaces.  I tend to use the socket interface as it naturally works over a network.  Pipes can only be read/written by software running on the Pi.

Comment: the only thing i'm worring about now is the resolution (it's already enough).. 8bit 255 ... is there a way to increase that to 1024? on servoblaster i used us (microseconds)

Comment: but using sockets you need a special devices that is able to control that specific socket... and it does not work over http using a simple html page right? using websockets i just need to open a "modern" browser and point it to the raspberry... am i correct?

Comment: Yes, but you compromise the update rate.  The default resolution at 800Hz is 250 (It's scaled to 255).  If you drop the update rate to 400Hz the resolution becomes 500, if you drop the update rate to 200Hz the resolution becomes 1000.  Alternatively you could boost the sample rate when the pigpio daemon is started.  See this [table](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSetPWMfrequency). You are correct about the socket, it probably is simplest to use a pipe.

Comment: it looks like that at the nodejs side, writing it like i do, there is now way to flush. what problems could come up?

Comment: btw i open the stream and it remains open. closing it everytime would slower the nodejs. atm i'm totally using it only as passtrough. i open the server(websocket) and open the stream.Every incoming data is then directly pushed to the pipe.

Comment: I think the socket will actually be a more appropriate fit w/ node.  High level file interfaces can make assumptions that aren't always appropriate to things that aren't literally static, stored sequences of bytes (which may explain your "seek error" problem).

Comment: but the client (html&js) needs to talk with nodejs js has a native websocket api.. does it also have a native socket api?

Comment: btw i think you can't seek the /dev/pigpio stream. joan wrote the pigpio code. he knows.

Comment: @goldilocks "w/ node" means without? in that case i need to know how can i implements sockets with javascript? now everyone with a smart device can control this raspberry. no apps or anything else needed just a browser. Sockets != websockets and so i can't just connect a socket server without an external language that makes this possible.Each device would need to have a custom app that supports sockets.

Comment: "w/" = with, "w/o" = without. For hopefully obvious reasons, node includes a TCP socket implementation, and you can use that to communicate with pigpio *from the server,* not the client:  I don't mean you should replace your websocket, I mean you do this on the back the same as you would with a local database.  You're just replacing the `/dev/whatever` stuff with socket stuff. This is slightly more complicated in that it probably requires callbacks since node is asynchronous, but you're already familiar with how to do that if you've been using it at all.

Comment: i use also nodejs as webserver that outputs the html file to drive everything... loaded once it's stored in the device(localstorage & cache.manifest) and so i don't need to bother about a webserver(every other type of server).. the app also works if the webserver is offline, the websocket server needs to be online.  most of the real cpu/gpu(css 3d) intensive work is done with the client.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you don't even have to worry about the async event handling stuff -- you can just block and do your transfer *exactly the same as you are already doing with writing to a pipe*, except it's a socket.  Note that a websocket **is a TCP socket** so again, whatever node facility you are using, that part of the API must be available.

Comment: Just to make sure there is no further confusion:  I'm not saying you replace the websocket with something else.  You have the websocket application, which on the "front" has a TCP socket to the outside world (a websocket styled connection to your phone).  On the "back", you set up another socket, a connection to pigpio, and you pass the information through that way.